# Django ModelChoiceField choices not updating

Tags: python, django

Well, I'm stuck in that problem for quite long now.
Went to read some question / answers and blog, and at this point I don't understand why this is not working.

I'm gonna make my example as simple as possible.

Let's say I have a ModelMultipleChoiceField :

```
myfield = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=SomeObject.objects.none(),
    label='',
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        attrs={
            'class': 'mtlz-checkbox-group',
            'label': 'some label: '
        }
    ),
    required=False
)
```

I set my queryset to none cause I need to compute the result dynamically. Note that this is in a ModelForm and that this field is a field of my object that I needed to custom (with some custom widget).

Well now i'm changing the queryset in the `__init__()` method :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EquipeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.base_fields['myfield'].queryset = self.method()
```

Here `self.method()` is a method that's computing my queryset, and it's working fine.
So, whatever, the choices were not getting updated except when I refresh (just pressing f5, not cache and stuff). Continuing my reading, I read that `self.base_fields['myfield'].widget.choices` were cached and so I had to force the "refresh" too in my init :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EquipeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.base_fields['myfield'].queryset = self.method()
    self.base_fields['myfield'].widget.choices = self.base_fields['myfield'].choices
```

Using a pdb, I saw the choices were updated, and looks like the widget choices too. But still, when I first come on my form, the last choices are displayed and seemed to be cache. If I just press f5, again, it's now the right choices displayed.

In a last try I declared the all field in the `__init__()` method but it's just the same.

So what am I missing? Is there any other cache involved as my choices seem to  change in my `__init__()` but are always one turn late ?
Does that come from my custom widget (which herit from a normal widget) ?

For information, it's on django 1.11.

**EDIT:**
the `self.method()`:

```
def method(self):
    ids = []
    if not self.instance.attribute:
        for obj in SomeObject.objects.exclude(id=self.instance.id):
            ids += obj.members.all().filter(
                some_condiftion=False
            ).values_list('id', flat=True)

    return SomeOtherObject.objects.filter(is_superuser=False) \
                .exclude(id__in=ids).order_by('name')
```

`SomeObject.members` is a manytomany fields related to `SomeOtherObject`. That's why I have a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You say you hit F5, but if you do not refresh, then the choices are indeed not updated: forms are (unless with some extra tooling) rendered statically: the choices are in the HTML, so once the page is rendered the choices are not updated, until you refresh the page, no Ajax call happens by default (well there are ways to do that of course).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so what's the point to have a ```__init__()``` method where you can change everytime you call if whatever the choices in front are cached? I dispay the page for the first time, the queryset with none is rendered when my form has actually changed in the ```__init__``` and has never been rendered. Do you mean the render version is called just after the ```super()``` call in ```__init__()``` and I whatever I do after it won't change the html rendered?

Comment: @Bestattung: well `__init__` is the *constructor* of the form, so it us used if you would for instance do some advanced querying, or that the choices depend on parameters that are only known at the time the form is constructed (and thus not statically), for example if it depends on the user that makes the request.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah got that, so when i first call the form, it's set with ```SomeObject.objects.none()``` and then in my ```__init__()``` I do some queries to get what I actually want. Why is the first render the empty queryset when my compute has been made in the ```__init__()``` ? Again I'm talking of the first time i display it. When i refresh then it's fine. Why? The choices are finely set, why does it look like everything in the ```__init__()``` ignored  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are updating `self.base_fields`, which is the fields dict of the *class*, rather than `self.fields`, which is the copy on the instance.

Since `fields` is already created by the time you update `base_fields`, it uses the old version of the choices; the next time you render the page, it will use the version created this time.

Comment: looks like now my first queryset is always used ```SomeObject.objects.none()``` so now it's always empty. I just replaced ```base_fields``` with ```fields```. Actually my ```ModelMultipleChoiceField``` is a custom one herited from ```ModelMultipleChoiceField```. I just did it to change the ```label_from_instance()``` method. Don't know if that change anything

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you perhaps show `self.method()`?

Comment: Are you still setting the widget choices separately? You shouldn't need to do that. But if you are, are you sure you're not referencing `base_fields` there?

Comment: Yes that's perfect thank you. I was still manually setting the choices, and refereing to the base_fields. It's working like a charm now !.